# Where is teamcity vcs root property name?

Tags: teamcity

In teamcity documentation:

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-VCSProperties

It refers to a teamcity vcs root property name.

How do i find this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are located in the build parameters tab when you click on a build.